# VS code equivalent new line shortcut for Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, shortcut

I am new to Android Studio, and since in VS Code we could go to a new line using the shortcut "ctrl + enter" from anywhere in the line. Is there a similar shortcut for Android Studio too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Shift + Enter" could do the trick.

More shortcuts here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts